# Retrofit error when adding header

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp

I want to add header in retrofit.

```
@Headers({"Accept: text/event-stream"})
@GET("condition.json")
Call<String> getCondition();
```

But I always getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x20 at 6 in header name: Accept
```

any suggestion? thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't it be - {"Accept": "text/event-stream"}?

Comment: Try ```@Headers("Accept: text/event-stream")```.

Comment: @zhh still throwing an error

Comment: try @Headers("Accept: text/event-stream")
'{' is used when there are multiple headers.